# Firebase Phone Auth

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add Firebase Phone Auth to an app that I'm making in XCode. However, I'm having trouble with steps 3 of the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth) and everything after that.

I don't understand where my code is supposed to go. I try some of it already and I attached the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIPMi.png) of what I have done so far. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the verificationID valorised?

Comment: Have you uploaded APNs P12 certificates in Firebase Console?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the code seems right.
Now you must add another textfield where the user can add the verification code arrived from the SMS.

In a new method triggered by the user after adding the code you must set a FIRAuthCredential like in the code of the example:

```
FIRAuthCredential *credential = [[FIRPhoneAuthProvider provider]
credentialWithVerificationID:verificationID
            verificationCode:newTextField.text!];
```

And then do the signin with:

```
[[FIRAuth auth] signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential:credential
                                     completion:^(FIRAuthDataResult * _Nullable authResult,
                                                  NSError * _Nullable error) {
 if (error) {
   // ...
   return;
 }
 // User successfully signed in. Get user data from the FIRUser object
 if (authResult == nil) { return; }
 FIRUser *user = authResult.user;
 // ...
}];
```

Comment: I'm a little confused at how that would look could you please show me an example. As well as how would the code for the enter code look.

Comment: You must add two textfield (phone number and verification code) and two buttons (one to send the sms and one to verify the code). Your code is right, it create a verificationID that will match on the server side with the verification code.
Now save the verificationID of your code in a property (verificationID) and add the answer code in the second button IBAction and in the FIRUser *user you have the logged user.